# Почему строковый литерал в С++ это l-value?

Tags: c++, строковый-литерал

Например строковый литерал: "Hello, world!" не может стоять слева от оператора присваивания. Тогда, как он может являться леводопустимым выражением?

```
"WTF" = "Hello, world!"; // ошибка компиляции
```

> **l-value**:
>
> - Выражения, непосредственно обозначающие объект, non-modifiable в случае const-квалификации. Например, имя переменной, параметра функции и т.п.
> - Выражения ссылочных типов. non-modifiable в случае const-квалификации. В частности, результат вызова функций, возвращающих объекты по ссылке; выражения, состоящие из имен ссылочных переменных; операции преобразования к ссылочному типу и т.д.
> - Результат встроенной операции разыменования (*) — lvalue указуемого типа; non-modifiable в случае const-квалификации.
> - Результат встроенных префиксных операций ++, --.
> - Имя функции.
> - Имя массива.
> - Строковые литералы.
>
> **r-value**:
>
> - Выражения, обозначающие временные объекты. В частности, результат вызова функций, возвращающих объекты не по ссылке; результат встроенных операций +, -. > *, / и т.п.; явное создание временной переменной int() или C(); преобразования не к ссылочным типам и т.д.
> - Результат встроенной операции взятия адреса (&) — rvalue типа указатель.
> - Результат встроенных постфиксных операций ++, --.
> - Литералы, за исключением строковых (например, числовые литералы).
> - Константы перечислений.

Comment: В том то и дело, что данная строка не будет компилироваться. Но в соответствии со стандартом должна, ведь строковый литерал там это l-value, то есть он может стоять слева от оператора присваивания.

Comment: Уважаемый @Michael, что, по-Вашему, должно произойти в результате такого присвоения?

Comment: @BuilderC Что должно произойти? Ошибка компиляции. Это вроде бы, даже в комментарии указано.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Строковый литерал в С++ по всей строгости - это константа, и уже по одному этому участвовать в присвоении не может. Более того, в 2.14.5.12 сказано: *The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined.*

Далее, по сути это - массив, а массив опять же в присвоении ну никак не участвует.

В 3.10.9 говорится: *"If an expression can be used to modify the object to which it refers, the expression is called modifiable. A
program that attempts to modify an object through a nonmodifiable lvalue or rvalue expression is ill-formed."*

Наш же lvalue явно немодифицируемый.

Впрочем, само понятие lvalue имеет несколько иной смысл, чем приписываемый вами.

*An lvalue (so called, historically, because lvalues could appear on the left-hand side of an assignment
expression) designates a function or an object.*

Тут главное не то, что исторически они могли быть слева в выражении присваивания, а то, что это объект в памяти, от которого можно взять адрес. А получить адрес строкового литерала вполне можно, и *в этом смысле* это lvalue.

*По-моему, так... (с) Пух*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, в присвоении участвовать не может. В этом, никто на самом деле и не сомневается. Тогда каким образом строковый литерал может оказаться слева от оператора присваивания? Можете привести примеры? Ведь, в противном случае строковый литерал будет являться rvalue, подобно числовому литералу.

Comment: Забегая вперёд: константная переменная также не может участвовать в присвоении, но несмотря на это выступает в качестве lvalue при инициализации. const int lvalue = 5;

Comment: @Michael, при инициализации то, что стоит слева не является выражением и называться lvalue _не может_, только то, что справа (т.е. то чем инициализируется объект) является выражением и может относится к lvalue, prvalue etc.

Comment: @ixSci это хорошее уточнение! Благодарю.

Comment: В переводе - *lvalue обозначает функцию или объект*. Какое-то конкретное место в памяти, для которого в принципе можно получить адрес (в принципе - потому что оптимизатор может вообще разместить его в регистре, например). Взаимоотношение его с **оператором присваивания**, по-моему, ни при чем - если и говорится в стандарте о нем, то как о assignment expression, т.е. о выражении присваивания...

Comment: @Harry, не может ничего такого оптимизатор (отобрать у нас возможность). Если мы можем (по стандарту) получить адрес, то мы его получим. Если же мы не получаем нигде адрес, тогда и только тогда оптимизатор может разместить объект там, где понятие адреса не существует. Другими словами, если мы можем получить адрес чего-то, тогда это lvalue. И, если не ошибаюсь, у любого lvalue можно получить адрес (по крайней мере исключений я не припомню).

Comment: @ixSci Естественно, получим :) Вы просто не поняли, что я хотел сказать. Если вас этот адрес не интересует, то оптимизатор его может заткнуть в регистр. Но если вы захотите его получить - то, понятно, что будет хранение в памяти и, соответственно, адрес. Впрочем, что я повторяю, что вы написали (и что написал я до того, как стали писать вы :))? По-моему, все предельно ясно.

Comment: @Harry, значит не так понял. Прошу прощения.

Comment: @ixSci Да никаких проблем, нормальная рабочая ситуация :)

Comment: @Harry > _"**А получить адрес строкового литерала вполне можно, и в этом смысле это lvalue**"_   Каким образом? Можете привести пример?

Comment: @Michael `const char * prt = "Hello, Dolly!";` Здесь `ptr` - адрес в памяти, где располагается этот литерал.

Comment: @Harry то есть напрямую никак?  `&"Dolly is watching you";` Просто, я вижу здесь 2 выражения, вместо одного: указатель слева от оператора присваивания в качестве lvalue и строковый литерал справа от оператора присваивания, также в качестве lvalue.

Comment: Другими словами, адрес одного **lvalue** присваивается другому **lvalue**

Comment: Почему же никак? http://ideone.com/qPyz2A

Answer (score 1):

lvalue не значит, что такое выражение всегда может стоять слева от оператора присваивания. К примеру, пусть у Вас есть `const int meConst = 5;`, `meConst` в выражении `meConst = 6;` является lvalue, но пример всё равно собрать не удастся, т.к. нельзя изменять `const int`. То же самое со строковым литералом: да — это lvalue, нет — его нельзя модифицировать.

И небольшая, но релевантная цитата из C11[6.3.2.1]:

> **A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type**, does
>   not have an incomplete type, does not have a constqualified type, and
>   if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including,
>   recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or
>   unions) with a constqualified type.

Comment: l-value может стоять, как слева от оператора присваивания, так и справа от него. r-value может стоять только справа. Да, строковый литерал это не просто l-value, это ещё и non-modifiable l-value. То есть сам строковый литерал не может быть измененён, но всё таки от этого он не перестаёт быть леводопустимым выражением.

Comment: Например, значение константной переменной, вы также не можете изменять. Но в связи с тем, что она подобно строковому литералу является non-modifiable lvalue, при инициализации вы поставите её слева от оператора присваивания.

Comment: @Michael, ещё раз: никакого «леводопустимого выражения» в стандарте нет, есть понятие lvalue, которое используется в стандарте, чтобы минимизировать размазывание одного и того же по всему стандарту. Нигде нет никаких упоминаний того, что lvalue можно модифицировать. Строковый литерал имеет тип `const char[N]`, а, согласно мною приведённой цитате, изменять массив нельзя. Что касается второго комментария — перечитайте ещё раз ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я перечитал еще раз. Вы пытаетесь ответить на вопрос: "Почему нельзя изменять строковый литерал?". Но вопрос совсем про другое, и наверно это не случайно. Потому-что, если бы я хотел спросить, почему строковый литерал - это константа, то я бы так и сделал. А ответ был бы очевиден: "потому-что его нельзя изменять".

Comment: Также не понятно, почему вы проводите знак равенства между строковым литералом и массивом. И на основании этого выводите: "если массив - это lvalue, а литерал - это массив, значит и литерал это lvalue". Да, строковый литерал может быть представлен в виде массива, но во-первых это разные сущности, а во-вторых из этого совершенно ничего не следует.

Comment: Возьмем числовые литералы, они тоже могут быть представлены в виде массива. Или как вы пишете, могут иметь тип const int[N]. Но из этого, совершенно не следует, что по этой причине они становятся леводопустимыми значениями. Например, вы не можете написать 7 = x; А вот наоборот вполне, поскольку числовой литерал это всегда rvalue.

Comment: На счет терминологии. И понятия "леводопустимое выражение/значение". Его действительно там нет. Как нет и других русских слов. Наверно потому-что сам стандарт написан на английском языке?

Comment: @Michael, «Также не понятно, почему вы проводите знак равенства между строковым литералом и массивом». Потому что строковый литерал это и есть массив. Он не «может быть» массивом, он только массивом быть и может. Если Вам всё ещё не понятно, то почитайте стандарт C++14 [lex.string]p8